# No debugging symbols in gdb even when compiling with -g flag

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, gdb, debug-symbols

I am trying to compile my program with debugging symbols for use in gdb. I have added the -g flag to my makefile but I still get "Reading symbols from ...(no debugging symbols found)" when I load the program in gdb. What is wrong??

Here is a stripped down example of my makefile which should have the relevant bits:

```
CPP = g++
CFLAGS = -c -g -Wall

$(BIN): $(OBJ)
 $(CPP) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)

<test.o>: <test.cpp>
 $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) <test.cpp> -o <test.o>
```

If you'd like to see the whole thing you can go here instead, though I don't *think* it's necessary:

http://pastebin.com/vGNjy0ga

Miscellaneous notes.. I'm compiling with MinGW on Windows and I have SFML and OpenGL as dependencies.

And no, the -s flag is nowhere to be found in my makefile.

Comment: Can you confirm with `make -n` that you are indeed getting the `-g` flag on your compile line?

Comment: F:\rowdump\rom\ROMV>make -n
g++ -Wall src/obj/core.o src/obj/image.o src/obj/gnd.o src/obj/gat.o src/obj/world.o src/obj/rsw.o src/obj/camera.o src/obj/rsm.o src/obj/main.o -o romv -Wl,--enable-auto-import,-subsystem,windows -lsfml-main -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lopengl32 -lglu32

It's not there! Weird.. And my -ansi and -pendantic flags are gone too.

Edit: Sorry for wall of text. Didn't realize it was gonna turn out like this.

Comment: the output that Kobie pasted is for default target, which is for linking, and there is no -g flag there. I just confirmed on Ubuntu that that flag is not needed during linking only at compile time. I think you should try "make -n test.o" to see what command is used to compile.

Comment: As a side note, by convention you use `CXXFLAGS` for C++ and `CFLAGS` for plain C.

Answer (score 6):

Ahh. I'm very sorry. It turns out the "clean:" portion of my makefile is broken. Thus when I used make clean nothing happened. Deleting the .o files manually fixed the problem. The flags work perfectly now. Thanks to everyone who posted anyway! This can be deleted now.

Comment: And oddly even though make -n shows that my -g flag has been stripped, in actuality it has not.

Comment: binW has a comment above that your `make -n` is only showing the linking portion, not the compiling portion. Make sure you are looking at `make -n test.o` only.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue when using a makefile I inherited on some old F77 code. I tried all the flags people recommend (-g -ggdb ...etc.)
the solution was run **make clean**
If you don't have that or know what it means, basically delete all the compiled (.o) files.

the makefile didn't know to recompile since only flags were changed, so I wasn't actually compiling with -g or -ggdb when I thought it was. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

try to replace

```
$(BIN): $(OBJ)
 $(CPP) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)
```

with

```
$(BIN): $(OBJ)
 $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) -o $(BIN) $(OBJ) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)
```

(edit)
Note: -c option will not work with executable

Comment: That's not going to work, because the final executable can't use `-c`.  Also, it seems (from a quick test on g++ 4.4.1 on GNU/Linux) that you don't need `-g` when linking.

Comment: My bad, Yes you are right -c options will not work with executable

Answer (score 1):

I dont have much experience with Mingw but try replacing -g with -ggdb. This may solve your problem. According to gcc man page

> Produce debugging information for use
>   by GDB.  This means to use the most
>   expressive format available (DWARF 2,
>   stabs, or the native format if neither
>   of those are supported), including GDB
>   extensions if at all possible.

Comment: On my (GNU/Linux g++) manual, regular `-g` says, "GDB can work with this debugging information."

Comment: DWARF 2 is mainly used to get the value of MACROS while debugging

Comment: I have tried with `-g`, as well as `-g -ggdb`. Only the latter resulted in readable symbols.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `-g` when linking the object into a binary code.

```
CPP = g++
CFLAGS = -g -Wall

$(BIN): $(OBJ)
 $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

<test.o>: <test.cpp>
 $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) -c <test.cpp> -o <test.o>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think you need -g even while linking.