# Debugging in Code::Blocks doesn't seem to work - missing debugging symbols

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc, codeblocks, debug-symbols

I'm trying to debug a program in Code::Blocks. I followed [this guide](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Debugging_with_Code::Blocks) and [this short video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6CGH9Z19dS8) as far as I could, but **the debugger doesn't stop at breakpoints**...

I saw a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107325/debugging-in-codeblocks) which remained unsolved (I wasn't sure if I should bump it or open a new one with more details), I do have the "Produce debugging symbols [-g]" flag checked. Optimizations and "Strip all symbols [-s]" are also all disabled. I even tried the flag -ggdb [as suggested there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568461/no-debugging-symbols-in-gdb-even-when-compiling-with-g-flag), no success either.

I'm using TDM-GCC 4.5.2 (I just upgraded, previously I had the same issue with 4.5.1), and the debugger is GNU gdb (GDB) 7.2 (previously same issue with GDB 7.1). I'm on Windows 7 x64, using Code::Blocks SVN 7040 (that's the latest nightly build, as as far as I know they recommend them over the not often updated stable builds) (I had the same issue in SVN 6931).

Finally, I also noticed that the debugger complains about the lack of debugging symbols, here's the output in the debugger window:

```
Build succeeded
Selecting target: 
Debug
Adding source dir: G:\[...]\IPCMB3\
Adding source dir: G:\[...]\IPCMB3\
Adding file: bin\Debug\IPCMB3.exe
Starting debugger: 
done
Registered new type: wxString
Registered new type: STL String
Registered new type: STL Vector
Setting breakpoints
Reading symbols from G:\[...]\IPCMB3/bin/Debug/IPCMB3.exe...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.2
Child process PID: 6044
Program exited normally.
Debugger finished with status 0
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you copy here the entire command line for the build process? It might help more

Comment: Hi, I just searched around for 10 minutes to avoid asking such a basic question, but didn't manage to find out: where do you find the build command line in Code::Blocks?

Comment: The build commandline is in the little window on the bottom. If the debugger complains about no symbols, there are two possibilities. Either you _do not_ have "Produce debugging symbols" enabled, or you _do have_ "Strip all symbols from program" enabled. You find both by right-clicking on your project and choosing "Build settings...". Make sure that symbols are produced, and not stripped. Be sure to always do a full rebuild when changing those settings.

Comment: Hm, I already looks there but couldn't find it. Are we both talking about the "Logs & others" window? (that's the window I have at the bottom). If yes, when I compile, the only tabs that get populated are "Build logs" and "Build messages". Neither of them contain the build command line. For instance here's the build log: http://img830.imageshack.us/img830/6076/compiledebug.png

Comment: go under settings->compiler debugger->Global compiler settings. Under build options or other settings you will find 'compiler logging'. Set that to 'Full Commandline' and rebuild. Then edit your post here and post the build log you get.

Answer (score 10):

i dont know if u solved it already but i had the same problem and just solved it!!
i have searched *a lot* all over and eventually the problem was....

**non ASCII chars on the project path !!**

i had some hebrew letters on the folder path where my files are located !!
i changed it to regular english letters and the debugger worked!!

Edit: just to make it clear - all i did eventually is to **change the folder name in the file system** from hebrew to english

Comment: how did u actually change it?

Comment: i just changed the folder name in my file system

Comment: yup - C::B has that issue: http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Debugging_with_Code::Blocks#Path_with_spaces... i lost 5 hours today trying to configure cdb with c::b